# Django: AttributeError: module 'todo.views' has no attribute 'delete_item'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a to-do app with Django. Users can add an item and now I'm trying to implement the functionality for deleting an item.

When defining the view to delete an item I get his error: AttributeError: module 'todo.views' has no attribute 'delete_item'.

I checked many forums and videos and to me the code seems right. Any suggestions please? Thank you.

Models:

```
from django.db import models

class TodoItem(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()
```

Views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import TodoItem
from .forms import ItemForm

def delete_item(request, todo_id):
    item = TodoItem.objects.get(pk=todo_id)
    item.delete()
```

URLs:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from . import views

path('delete/<todo_id>/', views.delete_item, name='delete_item')
```

HTML:

```
<a href="{% url 'delete_item' things.id %}">
   <button class="button is-danger is-outlined">Delete</button>
</a>
```

the error message I get when I run the server: AttributeError: module 'todo.views' has no attribute 'delete_item'